# Error adding IP whitelist to Laravel 5 maintenance mode

Tags: php, laravel

I'm configuring maintenance mode in Laravel. I'm trying to add in an IP whitelist.

When I run this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckForMaintenanceMode
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
         if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance() &&
             !in_array($request->getClientIP(), ['127.0.0.1']))
         {
             return response('Be right back!', 503);
         }

         return $next($request);
     }
}
```

I get this error:

> Undefined property: App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::$app

Can someone tell me what's the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

As of Laravel 5.6.21, this functionality is now built into Laravel. The `php artisan down` command now takes `--allow` parameters which lets you specify the IP addresses to allow to access the site.

So, instead of making any customizations, you'd just need to run `php artisan down --allow=127.0.0.1`.

### Original

You're using `$this->app`, but your class doesn't have an `$app` property. You can either just use the `app()` helper method, you can inject the `Application` into your middleware, or you can extend Laravel's `CheckForMaintenanceMode` class, which will take care of all that for you.

#### Extend Laravel:

```
class CheckForMaintenanceMode extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode
```

#### Dependency Injection:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;

class CheckForMaintenanceMode
{
    /**
     * The application implementation.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application
     */
    protected $app;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application  $app
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
         if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance() &&
             !in_array($request->getClientIP(), ['127.0.0.1']))
         {
             return response('Be right back!', 503);
         }

         return $next($request);
     }
}
```

#### app() Helper

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
     if (app()->isDownForMaintenance() &&
         !in_array($request->getClientIP(), ['127.0.0.1']))
     {
         return response('Be right back!', 503);
     }

     return $next($request);
 }
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Much thanks! Also, is there are anyway to do php artisan down without command line ? If the website is hosted how to get it into maintenance mode ?

Comment: @feknaz I just updated the question, so make sure you're seeing the latest update. I'd suggest extending Laravel's class, as that seems like what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @feknaz That should be asked as another question so that anyone else with the same question can search and find the answer.